# NodeJS: any server sided scripting akin to PHP/eRuby?

Tags: php, node.js, scripting, eruby

I can't help but note that no matter how much I google, NodeJS doesn't seem to have any notion of server sided scripting, akin to PHP, eRuby, and what not.
That is, embedding code in HTML pages that gets processed before sending the pages to the client.

Is there any module that does this?

It shouldn't be too hard to make with regular expressions and the evil eval(), but it's pretty weird that nobody would have made this by now, seeing how it's the only sane way to send dynamic pages as far as I know.

Comment: There are actually quite a [few](http://paularmstrong.github.io/node-templates/) Node.js server side template systems.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize they are referred to as template systems.

Comment: They kind of have a lot of names, HTML rendering is most accurate, but yeah template libraries, templating engine, etc. But really just any system that builds an HTML document dynamically from server.